# asp.net repeater select ID with Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I hope i make sense this, i have a repeater and on click of a button, the corresponding div should open up, I can do this when it is hardcoded however since its a repeater there will be different IDs. Here is my repeater;

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptProfileStatus" OnItemDataBound="rptProfileStatus_OnItemDataBound"
    runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li class="bar1">
            <a name="jh"></a>
            <div align="left" class="post_box">
                <div class="itembottom">
                    <span class="date">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDate" Font-Underline="false" 
                             ForeColor="white" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </span>
                    <span class='feed_link'>
                        <a href="#" runat="server" class="comment" id="ahrefReply"></a>
                    </span>
                    <span class="commentsno">
                        <a href="#" class="commentsnr" id="2">2 comments</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <span class="delete_button">
                    <a href="#" id="A2" class="delete_update"></a>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div id="fullbox" class="fullboxahrefReply"></div>
            <div id="commentload"></div>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here is the jquery which i am trying to get to call it, it works now however when i start changing the ID's i will have a problem, how do i solve this;

```
//Comment Box Slide
$("[id$=ahrefReply]").live("click", function () 
{

    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    $(".fullbox" + "ahrefReply").show();
    $("#c" + "ahrefReply").slideToggle(300);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the anchor's click event, you can do something like,

```
click="YourFunction(<%# ((YourClass)Container.DataItem).Id %>)"
```

Then handle the id in your function.  You will have to modify this to work with your situation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try just walking up the DOM.  Something like this:

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('fullboxahrefReply').show()
```

Comment: Hi tried this and it didnt work, have you got any other suggestions? This is what i tried;                                                   
 $(this).parent().parent().find('.fullbox').show()
 $(this).parent().parent().find('.comment_box').slideToggle(300)